# Кроссдоменная авторизация между доменами второго и третьего уровней

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Авторизация происходит средствами ajax, php-скрипт расположен на домене первого уровня. База данных одна, домен третьего уровня является поддоменом того же домена второго уровня. Нужно, чтобы авторизация работала на обоих доменах. Авторизация осуществляется с помощью глобального массива $_SESSION. Как же реализовать кроссдоменную авторизацию?

Comment: Вам нужно чтобы во первых $_SESSION читалась из базы,а не из файла, а во вторых чтоб кука с session id была доступна на поддоменах. Думаю кто-нибудь раскроет тему подробнее.

Comment: @Darth $_SESSION у меня и читается из базы, это же сессионный массив, ка он может читаться из файла? Про куку читал, но толком не понял, как реализовать и, пишут, что уязвимый метод, небезопасный.

Comment: Вообще то по умолчанию $_SESSION хранится в файле.. Как называется таблица с сессиями в вашей базе? А про куку все просто - у нее должно быть поле domain с точкой перед доменом первого уровня (`.site.ru`), тогда она будет работать и на поддоменах.

Comment: @Darth c $_SESSION столкнулся, когда корзину делал, открывал сессию и создавал ключ $_SESSION['cart']. Сейчас по аналогии создаю $_SESSION['auth']. Даже и не думал, что можно как-то посмотреть таблицу, в которой массив хранится. Я сам под него таблицу не создавал. Про куку не совсем понял. То есть я должен её создать в том же php-скрипте, в котором осуществляю авторизацию?

Comment: К сожалению больше чем я уже написал я не могу вам помочь. Написать полноценный ответ я не готов т.к. не пишу на php уже давно( Сессии у вас в файлах лежат наверняка, вам надо их в бд хранить если хотите с разных серверов иметь к ним доступ. А насчет куки можете не брать в голову - я нагуглил что php автоматически ставит точку перед доменом. Правда надо проверить что на субдомене он ставит её для корневого домена.

Comment: @Darth спасибо. вообще, думал, раз база данных одна и корневой домен у субдоменов один, то и сервер один

Comment: Сервер у вас и один может быть.. Тут уж я не знаю. Например DNS указывает и с корневого домена и с субдомена на один и тот же сервак, такое тоже может быть. Просто если сервер один, то у вас и проблем не должно было возникнуть. Разберитесь с этим и дополните вопрос. Я не Ванга, просто обрисовал как решить типичные проблемы по вашему вопросу) Надеюсь кто-нибудь из phpшников сюда зайдет и ответит вам полноценно

Comment: @Darth хорошо, спасибо. Буду разбираться дальше